# Inserting an extra plot into faceted grid, ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I would like to display a set of parameters in the `ggplot2` faceted plot format. Three of the parameters come from the same dataset and can be easily faceted. I'd now like to add a fourth plot into the grid, the dataset of which is a completely different length/value to the others (but still relevant to view together).

This is the best I have (terrible). Is there a way to exactly align the coordinates and theme? Thank you

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
data(iris)

a_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl,nrow=2,scales='free')+
  theme_bw()

b_plot<- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('imposter')+
  theme_bw()

vp <- viewport(width = 0.52, height = 0.5, x = 0.75, y = 0.25)

png("test.png")
print(a_plot)
print(b_plot, vp = vp)
dev.off()][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion would be to handle this in the data and let the plot faceting work naturally. (I'm using `dplyr` here to combine the datasets, but it's only for convenience. Any mechanism that provides a single set of columns to plot on should work.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

bind_rows(
  transmute(mtcars, x=mpg         , y=disp        , z=as.character(cyl)),
  transmute(iris,   x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, z="imposter")
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ z, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: faceted combo of mtcars and iris]

Comment: Very sleek. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the parameter `plot.margin` and `panel.spacing` in the them to customize the size of the background you are plotting. And then modify the viewport to width so it matches your other 3 plots. You will probably have to try some times but it is achievable.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

a_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl,nrow=2,scales='free')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.3,0,0), "cm"),
        panel.spacing= unit(1, "cm"))


b_plot<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('imposter')+
  theme_bw()

vp <- viewport(width = 0.49, height = 0.5, x = 0.75, y = 0.25)
print(a_plot)
print(b_plot, vp = vp)
```